# strange issue with date validation on language change

Tags: magento-1.9, admin-panel, validation

i am facing strange issue admin language change From `English`to `Dansk (Danmark) / dansk (Danmark)` give validation error.

My code

```
$dateFormatIso = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateTimeFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT);

        $fieldset->addField(
            'event_start_date', 'date', array(
            'name' => 'event_start_date',
            'label' => $this->__('Start Date'),
            'image' => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
            // 'input_format' => Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT,
            'format' => $dateFormatIso,
            'style' => 'width:161px',
            'time' => true,
            'class' => 'validate-date validate-date-range date-range-event_date-from'
            )
        );
```

**For English**

[image]

**For Dutch**

[image]

the difference i checked is in `time`  Dutch **15.29** English **15:29**

Comment: Did you try using FORMAT_TYPE_LONG instead of FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT

Comment: @DavidManners still the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For for your example we have for Danish systems the ISO formats:

1. long: `d. MMM y HH.mm.ss z`,
2. short: `dd/MM/yyyy HH.mm`,
3. full: `EEEE 'den' d. MMMM y HH.mm.ss zzzz`
4. medium: `dd/MM/y HH.mm.ss`

And all of those will error on date validation. What fun! Oddly enough for say English UK some fail and some don't.

So in the end the JS that is called by `validate-date` looks as follows:

```
['validate-date', 'Please enter a valid date.', function(v) {
    var test = new Date(v);
    return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || !isNaN(test);
}],
```

So let's start by using `Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_FULL` and see what happens. Using chrome's js debugging we can add a break point in the validation class.

We can see that the date passed in is '"lørdag '31en' 31. december 2016 12.02.07 %Zz%Zz"' and when we try to call `new Date(v)` we get "Invalid Date". Oh poop!

So what are the valid date string formats that we can use. Well I am no JS expect so I just looked into [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp) and there appear to be a lot but I think the safest way of doing this would be to use one date format such as using `Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT` and not using the user's date format.

So I would suggest updating your code to be:

```
'format' => Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT,
```

Now I know that the "core" will use the admin's date time format in short form.

```
$dateFormatIso = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateTimeFormat(
    Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT
);
```

But we already know this will break as I assume the functionality was only tested with a limited set of locale formats. This does mean that there are pages in the admin that might not work based on the user's locale if they try to validate the datetime!

Doing a quick search for `$dateFormatIso` will show you problems with this. I would also hate to think about the front-end problems this could cause.